# ¿A que se refiere "en vez de un millón pueden ser dos"?

Tags: letras-de-canciones, poesía

¡Feliz año nuevo a todos!  Mientras espero la cuenta atrás, escucho la canción clásica de Mecano "Un Año Más", donde en un verso cantan:

"Y decimos adiós y pedimos a Dios que en el año que viene a ver si en vez de un millón, pueden ser dos"

¿A que se refiere el millón y el dos?  La canción falta contexto suficiente como para especificar algo concreto.  ¿Alguien me la puede explicar?

Answer (score 2):

Yo siempre he pensado que se refería al dinero ganado durante el año, que a ver si al año siguiente puede ganar dos (millones de pesetas) en vez de un millón (de pesetas). Un sueldo normal en España en 1988, el año en que se publicó la canción, se situaba entre el millón y los dos millones de pesetas al año.

En todo caso, la expresión puede dar lugar a interpretaciones. Igual podría referirse a que al año siguiente Mecano podría vender dos (millones de copias de sus discos) en vez de un millón. Esta teoría se podría apoyar en el hecho de que el anterior disco de Mecano, *Entre el cielo y el suelo*, fue [el primer álbum español en superar el millón de copias vendidas](http://elpais.com/especiales/2016/mecano/1986-entre-el-cielo-y-el-suelo.html).

Comment: Al principio, pense que tuvo que ver con las desgracias de la vida... como por ejemplo... en vez de un millon de muertos en la guerra o en vez de un millon de problemas personales, pueden ser (tan solo) dos... pero en el contexto que das, me suena razonable.